# issue with Android command line tools

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, usb-debugging

I downloaded the latest version of the command line tools for Windows (commandlinetools-win-6200805_latest) but when I run the sdkmanager from the command line, I get this error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli

How can I fix this? I guess there is something else I need to download right?